# How to change the join type of a contained association per find() call?

Tags: cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.2

How to reset the type of joins in different places?

Here are my tables:

Tenancy Table

```
class TenancyTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('tenancy');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Properties', [
            'foreignKey' => 'property_id',
            'className' => 'property',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
```

Property Table

```
class PropertyTable extends Table
{

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('property');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->hasMany('Tenancies', [
            'foreignKey' => 'property_id',
            'className' => 'tenancy',
            'joinType' => 'LEFT'
        ]);
```

For example change the Tenancy join type to Right

```
 $setting = [
      'contain' => [
          'Tenancies' => [
              'joinType' => 'RIGHT'
          ]
      ]
 ];

$properties = $this->find('all', $setting)
       ->hydrate(false)
       ->select(['Property.id', 'Property.company_id', 'Property.address1', 'Property.postcode'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You would do it exactly the way you are showing it, ie by specifying the `joinType` option in `contain` settings.

However, since you are querying from the `Property` table, this will have no effect, as `hasMany` associations are being retrieved in a separate query, so no joins involved. It *would* work for `hasOne` and `belongsTo` associations, which are being retrieved in the same query.